# JSON for Elasticsearch: three fields and three queries

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, query-string

Is there any way to write by query_string this query?

> (field_one : "word_one" OR "word_two" OR "word_three") AND (field_one
> : "word_four" OR "word_five" OR "word_six") AND (field_two :
> "word_seven" OR "word_eigth" OR "word_nine")

Like this, but with three fields and three queries?

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "my_search_field"
              ],
            "query": "my_search_query"
          }
        }
        ]
    }
  }
```

I tried to write it using filter:

```
"filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": should_phrases_a, #words by field_one
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": should_phrases_b, #words by field_one
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": should_phrases_c, #words by field_two
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
        ]
```

Where should_phases_a/b/c look like list of:

```
{"bool": {"should": [{
                            "match_phrase": {
                              "field_one": "word_one"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    }
```

But it didn't worked for me. It was good only with one_field intersection (without part with should_phrases_c):

> (field_one : "word_one" OR "word_two" OR "word_three") AND (field_one
> : "word_four" OR "word_five" OR "word_six")

Comment: You tried use query string with [field names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names)?

Comment: @rabbitbr I know about the possibility to search one query by two fields ("fields": ["field_one", "field_two"], "query": "my_search_query"), but don't know how to do it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify fields in query

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": """
                  (field_one:word_one OR word_two OR word_three)
              AND (field_one:word_four OR word_five OR word_six)
              AND (field_two:word_seven OR word_eigth OR word_nine)
              """
    }
  }
}
```